# Если в проект C# WF добавить новый NuGet пакет обновит ли его ClickOnce

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget, clickonce

Разрабатываю приложение на C# WinForms .Net5, возникла потребность добавить в проект еще один NuGet пакет, при этом ClickOnce обновляется через сайт. Возник вопрос, при этом обновится ли нормально приложение, как с простым добавлением кода или нужны дополнительные замены?

Comment: Достаточно посмотреть на то, что вам выдает ClickOnce после публикации. Ну а увидите вы там папку, внутри которой будет ряд других папок (своя папка под каждую версию), ну а в папке версии будут все ваши файлы проекта, только с расширением `.deploy`, ну а также будет файл `.manifest`, в котором будет описана структура вашего проекта, с именем, размером и хэшем каждого файла. Собственно, вот вам и ответ - клиент должен получить все то, что в папки версии, если там есть нужная .dll (а она у вас там будет, ибо проект после NuGet будет зависеть от нее), то и эту библиотеку он тоже получит.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тянет на полноценный ответ, предлагаю оформить

Comment: @aepot Оставлю это другим.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста как полный, закрою вопрос, поскольку ответ достаточно полезный

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EvgeniyZ написал:

> Достаточно посмотреть на то, что вам выдает ClickOnce после публикации. Ну а увидите вы там папку, внутри которой будет ряд других папок (своя папка под каждую версию), ну а в папке версии будут все ваши файлы проекта, только с расширением .deploy, ну а также будет файл .manifest, в котором будет описана структура вашего проекта, с именем, размером и хэшем каждого файла.
>
> Собственно, вот вам и ответ - клиент должен получить все то, что в папки версии, если там есть нужная .dll (а она у вас там будет, ибо проект после NuGet будет зависеть от нее), то и эту библиотеку он тоже получит.